# Finding an angle between two vectors

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, vectors, triangles

I am trying to answer part $d)$ by using my answer to part $c)$. From what I can see, the only possible way to do this is to find the lenght of $AB$ and $OB$, and, using the angle in part $c)$, apply the sine rule to find angle $OAB$. Are there are any quicker ways to find angle $OAB$ by using my answer to part $c)$?

[image]

Comment: Find vector b, take dot product, find $cos(OAB)$

Comment: We have to use the answer to part $c)$.

Comment: Then you can apply sine law in triangle OAB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the answer to part C. The vector from $A$ to $B$ is
$$\mathbf{u}=\langle6-2,4-4,2-6\rangle=\langle4,0,-4\rangle$$
and the vector from $A$ to $O$ is
$$\mathbf{v}=\langle-2,-4,-6\rangle$$
The angle between these is
$$\theta=\arccos \left(\frac{\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v}}{|\mathbf{u}||\mathbf{v}|}\right)=\arccos \left(\frac{16}{4\sqrt{2}\times2\sqrt{14}}\right)=\arccos\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{7}}\right)\approx67.8^\circ$$

Comment: That's more like it! Given a "+1" now. Although it doesn't meet the criteria of using the angle from part (c)...

Comment: Initially it seemed to me that the question used the word "hence" to indicated that part D could be answered in the same fashion as part C.

Comment: They would use "similarly" to indicate that. "Hence" in Maths questions always means "using the result from the previous section"

Answer (score 1):

The questioner is right to suspect that it must be quite easy:

Length $OA$ = length $OB$.

Triangle $AOB$ is isosceles.

Now use the angle you have. So it is "hence"

Comment: Yeah, that was my initial idea too but I thought that for 2 marks that would have been too much work, and so I wondered if there were any other quicker methods.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but did you have to calcuiate $OA$ and $OB$ to know the triangle was isosceles, or did you find out otherwise?

Comment: Point $A$ is at $(2,4,6)$ while point $B$ is at $(6,4,2)$ which makes it obvious that they have the same lengths. They have the same components, except the $x$ and $z$ are switched.

Comment: I agree with @cheesyfluff that it is obvious. It asks you to use the components of $\vec {OA}$ and $\vec {OB}$ for part (c) so they expect you to have spotted that that they are equal length.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't actually found the co-ordinates, and I thought that perhaps you used some clever trick.